# How to limit phone number input lenght using formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm integrating in my project react-phone-number-input and formik libraries.
I want to limit phone number lenght to 18.
Below You can see the logic I'm using

```
<PhoneNumberInput
          id="patient.phone.number"
          values={number}
          errors={phoneNumberError}
          touched={phoneNumberTouched}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          onChange={(num: string | null) => phoneNumberHandler(num)}
          placeholder={t('profile.phone')}
          label={t('profile.phone')}
        />

  const phoneNumberHandler = (num: string | null) => {
    if (num && num.length >= 18) return;
    if (num && num.length < 18) {
      console.log('num', num);
      const phoneNumber = parsePhoneNumber(num);
      console.log('phoneNumber', phoneNumber);
      if (phoneNumber) {
        formik.setValues({
          ...formik.values,
          patient: {
            ...formik.values.patient,
            phone: {
              number: phoneNumber.number,
              region: phoneNumber?.country || '',
              countryCode: phoneNumber?.countryCallingCode || '',
            },
          },
        });
      }
    }
  };
```

What is strange is that when num.length >=18 console.log('num') and console.log('phoneNumber') are not updating, nor console.log(values) from all formik values are not updated, so from this perspective it seems that code works properly.
For some reason I don't know why, phone number input fields which is displayed on the screen is updating all the time, no matter of num.length.

Can You suggest where I have mistake in the code ?